# Separation of Independent Probabilities with Condition

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

This question comes out of the following proof.

Two independent random variables, $X_1, X_2$. $X_1$ occurs with probability $p$ and $X_2$ with $(1-p)$.

The sum, $N = X_2+X_1$ has $P(N=i+j) \sim Poisson(\lambda)*$.

**(see below re. dodgy notation)*

If $N=i+j$ then,

$$
P(X_1=i, X_2=j) = P(X_1=i, X_2=j, N = j+i) = P(X_1=i, X_2=j\ |\ N = j+i)P(N=i+j)
$$

**This is where I have issues**. I'm not sure why I can't do the following:

$$
\tag{1}
P(X_1=i, X_2=j\ |\ N = j+i) \sim Binomial(N,p)
$$

and by independence,

$$
\tag{2}
P(X_1=i, X_2=j\ |\ N = j+i) = P(X_1=i\ |\ N = j+i)P(X_2=j|\ N = j+i))
$$

this gives me the wrong answer though as I get $Binomial(N,p)^2$ as a result.

- A side question: What is the proper notation for saying that $P(N=i+j)$ follows a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Equation (2) is wrong. Once $X_1+X_2$ is held fixed, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are no longer independent! If you know $X_1+X_2$, and you know $X_1$, $X_2 is easily determined, which contradicts the independence of these quantities...

Comment: Also, equation (1) doesn't really make ense. The expression to the left of the "$\sim$" has two parameters $i$ and $j$, but binomial distributions are univariate...

Comment: Finally, it's not really clear what you're trying to show. Do you want to *prove* that $X_1+X_2 \sim \textrm{Pois}(\lambda)$, or is that an assumption?

Comment: notation: *What is the proper notation for saying that $P(N=i+j)$ follows a Poisson distribution?* I do not know the correct notion that's why I ask... I know how to finish the proof I just wasn't sure why approaching it from this angle wasn't valid. You gave an excellent answer though in your first comment. Thanks!

Comment: As for the notation, if $N = X_1+X_2$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then you usually write $N\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, not $P(N = i+j)\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. There are a variety of abbreviations; I use $N\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$. In general, if $Z$ follows some distribution "Name" with parameter "name", then $Z\sim\text{Name}(name)$.

Comment: I didn't complain about the notation you used to ask "Does $P(N=i+j)$ follow a Poisson distribution", or at least I didn't mean to. I complain that I'm not sure whether that statement is an *assumption* or something you want to *prove*. Although notation-wise, you should write $N \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, not $P(N) \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, since it's $N$ that is Poisson-distribution, not $P(N)$. But that's a technicality, since it was clear what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N=X_1+X_2$ for independent Bernoulli random variables $X_1, X_2$ then $N$ is *not* Poisson distributed, yet *nor* is it Binomial.

It is a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution); being the sum of two non-identical independent Bernoulli trials.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N=n)\; & =\; \mathsf P(X_1=0)\mathsf P(X_2=n)+\mathsf P(X_1=1)\mathsf P(X_2=n-1) & \big[n\in\{0,1,2\}\big]
\\[1ex] & = \; \begin{cases} (1-p)p  & : n=0 \\ (1-p)^2+p^2 & : n=1 \\ (1-p)p & : n=2\end{cases}
\end{align} $$